# Load an ASP.NET 2.0 aspx page using System.Reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, system.reflection

Can I load an stand alone aspx page in another stand alone aspx page using System.Reflection?

I am using the ASP.NET 2.0 Web site project model.

Comment: I checked the definition for "scaling issues" and found this.

Comment: I know this is not the best practice, but I am am trying to update parent aspx page from a child aspx page. I am not finding any ideas. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375977/calling-a-parent-page-code-behind-method-from-a-child-page-code-behind-aspnet-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.createinstancefromvirtualpath.aspx). Sample usage:

```
Page p = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/Default.aspx", typeof(Page))
```

This answers this specific question, although, based on your comments, I'm not sure that this is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about doing it using Reflection, which may well be possible, but you can capture the output of an aspx or asp page to a string writer using HttpContext.Server.Execute().
I have used this for rendering some complex email templates, but don't know if that is quite what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the following solution and it is what I exactly want to do:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Compilation;

Page p = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/mypage.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
MethodInfo MyMethod = p.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
MyMethod.Invoke(p, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a inherited class from UI.Page for your code behind page, you could use this way:
**set CONTEXT to your current http context**

```
Dim hndlr As IHttpHandler = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance("~/mypage.aspx", context.Server.MapPath("~/mypage.aspx"), CONTEXT)
Dim ipage As DerivedPage = DirectCast(hndlr, DerivedPage)
ipage.YourProperty= "Hello"
ipage.DoIt()
```

So you can have strong typed values and, if you'll change the sign of a method you'll be warned.

Comment: This will throw an error because the compiler will not find the hand variable.